# How can I get the PageInstance from the BackStack?

Tags: windows-phone

I'm trying to get the PhoneApplicationPage instance from the backstack entry, but I don't want to keep my own navigation list. I've seen a PageInstance that is a member of the JournalEntry of the BackStack from the debugger, but I'm thinking that is a DependentProperty of the JournalEntry and I can't access it in a "normal" way.

Is there a way to get the Page from the BackStack entry or via the Uri?

I'm guessing I'm out of luck, but I'm hopefull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get an instance from the back stack.

If I'm right, you want your page B to pass data to the previous page A. A simple solution is to create a property to a place where everybody can reach, for example in the App class. When something interesting happens in page B, set this property to a new value, and when the user navigates back to page A, you can read this property to update the page.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the Page from the BackStack entry or via the Uri?

No.